# minimizing the sum of weighted absolute distance

Tags: optimization, median

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ denote $n$ points in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space, and $w_1, \ldots, w_n \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ any non-negative weights.

$\arg\min_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}^d} \sum_{i=1}^n w_i | x_i-\mu| = median\{x_1, \ldots, x_n \}?$

I understand why the median of $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$ minimizes the function without the weights. But I am not sure if the median is what minimizes the function with the weights, should I use Lagrange multiplier to solve this?

Comment: The result claimed is incorrect when the $w_i$s are not equal. Consider the case $w_j < \epsilon$ for $j>1$ and $w_1$ very large. The minimiser then is very close to $x_1$, which need not be the geometric median of the $\{x_i\}$. I believe this equation is generally used to  define the *weighted geometric median*. This wiki article on the [Weber Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_problem) may be germane.

Comment: so, is there a closed solution for the minimum of the weighted geometric median for a finite number of points?

Comment: I don't get the term 'minimum of the median'. However, if you simply mean the median itself, I don't think so. IIRC there isn't one for the unconstrained median either. BTW, recall that the case where $w_i =1$ is also the definition of the median in the usual sense.

Comment: That link to the wikipedia page on the Weber problem was exactly what I needed. Thank you from the year 2020, @stochasticboy321.

Answer (score 3):

What minimizes your weighted is again the median !!! But not the median of $x_1,x_2,... $.

A value that minimizes your sum will be a number  $\mu $ such that

$$ \sum_{i\in \{1,2,...,n\}, x_i>\mu} w_i < \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}{2} $$

$$ \sum_{  i\in \{1,2,...,n\},\,\, x_i<\mu} w_i < \frac {\sum_{i=1}^n w_i}{2} $$

Note that this $\mu $ will also a median. It is a median of the random variable defined on the sample space  ${1,2,...,n} $ that sends  $i $ to $x_i $. In this probability space, the probability of occurrence of $i $ is  $\frac {w_i} {w_1+...+w_n} $

---

Opps! ! I just noted that your  $x_i $ can be vectors, therefore my answer only works when  $d=1$

Comment: How can I generalize your answer to multiple dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have stated is the weighted L1 median (sometimes called the weighted geometric median) of your data.  There are many references on the topic: 
https://www.google.com/search?q=l1+median

A concise reference along with an algorithm is:
http://www.stat.rutgers.edu/home/cunhui/papers/39.pdf

However, note that the Vardi-Zhang process needs to be adjusted for data having repeated values.  If you scan the literature, there are some references that describe this adjustment.